Help to identify addressable led type
I have addressable led garland, and i cant find led type to check datasheet for data signal timings.
I have tried ws28xx, sk65xx and apa10x timings, but none of them work.
I know that garland works because couple of leds start glowing green when i connect power.
I know where data input and output are located.
addressable led garland:

ws2812b on top, unknown led at the bottom:


Why won’t you look at the data line when the garland is operating with its normal controller.

@Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica unfortunately i don't have original controller.

the first LED may be defective

@jsotola I've cut several leds, and also taped in the middle of the strip, no results.
